# Can not setup wireless connection on debian - Intel Corporation Device 3166

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

With `lspci` I get the name of my network controller:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 3166 (rev 99)
```

With `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 3166` I get no results which means that `iwlwifi` does NOT support my newtork controller. How can I get my wireless to work?

**UPDATE**

I editet my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-iwlwifi`. Wireless still does not work..

**INFO**

- Debian: 8.7 (jessie)
- Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64

Comment: [Looks](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311656) like it's supported for newer versions of `iwlwifi`, which means you must upgrade your kernel. This might require a newer Debian distro. Or you can try to find the correct backport.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you! I editet my question. How can I procede? I would prefer the backport.. (if it doesn't work I can try to upgrade my kernel)

Comment: Googling for "debian jessie kernel backports" finds [this](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/kernel/) with kernel version 4.9 available. That's a bit more than 3.16. You need to upgrade the kernel, as I said. Upgrading the firmware is not enough.

Comment: I did `apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64`. On reboot I get a black screen with a white cursor on the left upper corner... When I hit the reset button, my machine boots again, I can interrupt the booting and select my old kernel..

Comment: Debugging kernel boot issues it probably a new question. Black screen points to trouble with the graphics card/framebuffer driver. Google for kernel options you can pass on boot to narrow down the problem. It's also possible that the kernel expects certain packages; see if there are docs about the backport. Eventually you'll have to upgrade the kernel at some time, anyway.

Comment: I `apt-get purged` the upgraded kernel and will retry! Thank you for your time and help!